# FOUC - why does it happen if render requires DOM & CSSOM?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked previously, but none of them seem to really answer my question, or at least, I'm misunderstanding them.

My understanding is that a browser can't / won't render the page until the DOM and CSSOM has been created. If that is indeed the case, why do we see FOUC?

I'm currently in the process of building a static site, it has 2 CSS files in the head, and 1 JS file in the footer (performs a bit of animation on `load` event), yet in Firefox, and Chrome (if I repeatedly hit refresh / hard refresh) I get a quick FOUC experience, and it's incredibly frustrating.

The strange thing is, is that if I place the JS above the CSS and within the `<head>`, the FOUC stops...

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening? I've tried removing the JS and still, if I repeatedly hit refresh, I experience FOUC.

Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: does the javascript affect the attribs, classes, or contents of the page? Also, can you confirm your're seeing un-styled actual text markup, rather than just background colors or BFcache remnants?

Comment: I think your assumption that nothing is rendered until everything is loaded is wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: @dandavis Hi and thanks for the help. Would the Git repo help? The JS does impact the page as I'm using anime.js to fade / translate a few things...With regards to BF cache remnants, I'm honestly not sure. I'm not navigating back and forth, only refreshing...

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the help. In that case, why is CSS described as render blocking if the browser can / will actually render the markup without it? The Wikipedia page says 'The browser may choose to first display the text, which it can parse the quickest.', however what rules is it using to decide whether to do this, or actually wait for the CSSOM?

Comment: I misread something in the wikipedia. When it said Chrome 50 prevented stylesheets injected by JS from blocking, I didn't notice that it was only talking about injected stylesheets.

Comment: But I think the basic answer is that it's browser-dependent how it decides whether to display the text before loading all the CSS.

Comment: Any browser usually uses 3 - 4 threads to load resources. Any of these threads can be intercepted (= delayed) by some other CPU tasks. That leads to more or less random finalizing of loading the resources, and the order is not predictable.

Comment: HTML standard says, that the head section is guaranteed to be loaded and parsed before the body sections is parsed. But the standard seems to be compromized by the modern browsers in favor of faster total loading ..? I can't recall this being an issue a decade ago.